# OSX map network drives on login WITHOUT finder windows popping up

Tags: macos, networking, hard-drive, mac, finder

I have followed some other tutorials to get OSX to mount my network drives when I log in, using the "**Users and Groups > Login Items**" method, which works fine, but this brings up a whole load of finder windows upon starting up the machine, which is both annoying and time consuming to deal with, as I have about 6 drives mapped, so every time I log on, OSX spews 6 finder windows randomly across the screen for me to have to deal with every single time I log in. Is there a workaround, perhaps using terminal or automator that will allow me to map these drives and not have to see these windows pop up every single time?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [another thread on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20185/14972). It’s an AppleScript / Automator solution that will **prevent Finder windows from opening on login**.

Answer (score 0):

By 'other tutorials' I'm assuming you went for the 'drop mounted drives to Login Items' method.

In Login Items - check the Hide box to stop it opening windows on mount.

Comment: That has always been ticked for all 6 drives, and they still pop up on login.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/RjwNkLS) is a pic of the login items

Comment: Any thoughts? I am still having this problem, and it is becoming increasingly annoying.